# Coefficients which depend on summation index for a Hamiltonian in sneg

Tags: physics, packages

I would like to perform some manipulations involving a pretty generic Hamiltonian of the form
$$
\hat{\mathcal H}=\sum\limits_{k,k^\prime}V_{k,k^\prime}\hat a_k^\dagger\hat a_{k^\prime}
$$
(where $V_{k,k^\prime}\in\mathbb C$)
using the sneg package.

Unfortunately, I find no way I would like to set $V_{k,k^\prime}$ as complex constants that depend on $k,k^\prime$ in sneg.
When I searched the documentation the only option I saw was `snegcomplexconstants` , with which I cannot specify the dependence on $k,k^\prime$.

So my question is:

How can I define coefficients which depend on the summation index?

---

Edit- What I have so far (I'll include a maybe slightly simpler example):

- I include `TBpack` (which in turn includes `sneg`): `
- I defined $\omega$ as a function (of $k$) and $\hat{\mathcal H}=\sum\limits_k\omega_k \hat a_k^\dagger\hat a_{k}$
- I tried to evaluate some commutator.

```
<<TBpack`
snegbosonoperators[a]
SetAttributes[\[Omega], NumericFunction]
H0 := sum[\[Omega][k] a[CR, k] a[AN, k], {k}]
sumFullSimplify[komutator[a[CR, 1], H0]]
```

Mathematica thinks $\hat a_1^\dagger$ cannot be pulled into the sum when trying to simplify the expression. However, if I delete the $\omega_k$, Mathematica pulls it into the sum, which makes me think that I haven't defined my $\omega_k$ properly.
I don't know how to use `snegcomplexconstants` in a way that signals that the constants depend upon the summation index.

Comment: You will want to add whatever code you have so far. Additionally, `sneg` is not a very common package, so you may have more luck contacting its support community (if one exists) or the package authors.